# Install PostgreSQL on Kubernetes with Helm 3

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a few microservices and one of them needs to use postreSQL. I configure this microservice using Helm 3.I have two different values.yaml per environments such as values.stage.yaml and values.prod.yaml.So my confusion is,

1. Should I independentyl install the PostreSQL? What I mean, in my scr code I have helm chart call helm/app. Should I create one more chart for PostreSQL? How can I configure the PostreSQL per environments.

2.In future, if one more microservice would like to use the same PostreSQL, what should I do to provide this feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your chart should declare `postgresql` as a [dependency](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#chart-dependencies), in Helm 3 in its `Chart.yaml` file.  (In Helm 2 there was [a separate `requirements.yaml` file](https://v2.helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#chart-dependencies).)  You will need to run `helm dep up` (`helm dependency update`) before deploying your chart, but then when you run `helm install` it will install both your application and its database dependency.

So your `Chart.yaml` can look roughly like

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: app
...
dependencies:
  - name: postgresql
    version: '^8'
    repository: @stable
```

(In Helm 3 you also need to [`helm repo add` the stable Helm charts repository](https://github.com/helm/charts#how-do-i-enable-the-stable-repository-for-helm-3).)

You can configure the database per environment in the same way you configure the rest of your application.  Database settings would be [nested under the subchart's name](https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts/#scope-dependencies-and-values); at the command line you might `--set postgresql.postgresqlPassword=...`, and in a YAML file you'd put database settings under a `postgresql:` key.

If you have a second service that needs PostgreSQL, it should declare a dependency in the same way and install its own independent copy of the database.  With database installation isolated inside containers this isn't considered particularly heavy-weight.  If your two services need to communicate, they should do it via a network (often HTTP) connection and not by sharing a database.

Comment: @appreciate for your useful response that will be open my horizon.. But it might be my fault ı forgot to specify, there is already stable chart in our private registry which I think to install postgresql independently..In this scenario should I use dependency again?

Comment: You can point at a different `repository:` without really changing this workflow.

Comment: Should I need helm registry plugin?  Because internally another unit has a postgresql image in private registry and needs to pull it from there.

Comment: This is all built-in functionality in Helm; if your local `helm` command can reach the chart registry then all you should need to do is `helm repo add` it.

Comment: understood. I think we need our own repository because.. I can able to reach chart registry but that chart is not suitable for helm 3.. Is there any easy way to convert it t Helm 3?

Comment: Without wrapping `@stable` in quotation marks, I got `Error: cannot load Chart.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 28: found character that cannot start any token` when running `helm dependency update`

Answer (score 0):

By default, Helm picks `values.yaml` of root directory of the chart.

To install same Helm Chart with different values, you can do something like,

```
helm install . -f values.stage.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks for your respose but this is not I want.. my question is how can I install the postreSQL and pass the values to different environment.

Comment: Should I install independently? so what I need to do to make a communication between my microservice and postreSQL?

Comment: Let's say, one instance of PSQL is created. Provide service name, username, password in the microservice. In microservice you will give will give something like,  jdbc:postgresql://psql-instance-1-service.namespace:5432/myusersdb.   

Again you install helm chart with different values.yaml to create another instance of Postgres

Comment: What is the best way to do this in microservices? Using configmap or any other solution to ensure following best practices? I could not find any examples for Helm 3